# Symfony how to translate data value in a form

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony

I have the following code in a buildForm and I want to obtain the translation of `'report_abuse'` but I can't find a way. Is it possible ?

```
class AbuseType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    $builder->add('subject', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => 'label.subject',
        'data' => 'report_abuse',
        'disabled' => 'true',
    ))

    // ...   
 }
```

Comment: did you add the `report_abuse` in one of the translation files? my understanding is that you want to translate the value that gets displayed in an input field `subject`?

Comment: Yes I have added the report_abuse in a xlf file and yes I wanted to translate the value displayed in the field, so I have cheated to get the value translated before injecting it in my object. I have answered to my question below.

Answer (score 2):

Try to explicitly set the `translation_domain`:

```
$builder->add('subject', TextType::class, array(
    // ...
    'translation_domain' => 'messages',
))
```

You can also do it for the whole `FormType` by adding this method into:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{    
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'translation_domain' => 'messages'
    ));
}
```

If it doesn't work, inject the `translator` in your `FormType` by registering it [as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service):

```
# services.yml
services:
    app.form.type.abuse:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\AbuseType
        arguments: [ "@translator" ]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

Call the translator directly:

```
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class AbuseType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    // ...

    $builder->add('subject', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => 'label.subject',
        'data' => $this->translator->trans('report_abuse', array(), 'messages'),
        'disabled' => 'true',
    ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. None of the two first have worked... I won't use the third one as it's "too much" for a translation, all the other parts are correctly translated but I'll keep it as an example of service

Comment: I can understand that it's overkill for you, but if you really need to translate the value of this option ... you'll need the translator, and so need to get it in your Type.

Comment: It's not a question of "overkill", but if Symfony has not let/set the possibility to translate data as for label it's because of a reason (which one ???). So I prefer finding another way, including not having the need to translate. But really thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did. I have injected the subject in the Abuse class as its value will be taken by default to build the form. i have also set the field as readonly in place of disabled, which causes the fields to be NOT submitted.

```
//FormController.php
    class FormController extends Controller
    {
        //...
        public function abuseAction(Request $request)
        {
            $subject = $this->get('translator')->trans('report_abuse');
            $abuse = new Abuse($subject);
           //...
        }
        //...
    }

//Abuse.php
    class Abuse
    {
        //...

        public function __construct($subject)
        {
            $this->setSubject($subject);
        }

    //...
    }

//AbuseType.php
class AbuseType extends AbstractType
{
    //...

    $builder->add('subject', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => 'label.subject',
        'attr' => array(
            'readonly' => true,
        )))

    //...
}
```